# PHP Regexp wrap elements to html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to fastest wrap numeric from string:

```
$txt = 'lorem 333888 <i data-some-1="111" data-some-2="222">444</i> 555 ipsum <b>666</b> 777 dol..';
```

Like that (wrap by `i` tag numbers: 333, 555, 666, 777 and 888):

```
$txt = 'lorem <i>333</i> <i data-some-1="111" data-some-2="222">444</i> <i>555</i> ipsum <b><i>666</i></b> <i>777</i> dol..';
```

Without 111, 222, 444.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$output = preg_replace('/ (\d+) /', ' <i>$1</i> ', $txt);
```

Output:

```
string(108) "lorem <i>333</i> <i data-some-1="111" data-some-2="222">444</i> <i>555</i> ipsum <b>666</b> <i>777</i> dol.."
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/cA8qqTTV)

Comment: Ok, I edited. Now I remove space by added 888 after 333.